# Raising an integer to a fractional power

Tags: rust, exponent

I have the code:

```
(i as f64).powf(2.0 / 5.0).floor() as u64
```

Is there a way of raising an integer to a fractional power without resorting to floating point?

(I could performing two separate integer power operations.  It would either overflow or lose a lot of precision, depending on the order.)

Comment: Under what circumstances would you expect to lose precision, other than in situations where the final result is not presentable as an integer?

Comment: If I did `i.pow(1/5).pow(2)` then `i.pow(1.5)` would be an integer and so would be rounded down *before* being raised to the fifth power.

Comment: But what value of `i` would make `i^(2/5)` an integer yet not make `i^(1/5)` an integer?

Comment: I want to effectively apply `.floor()` *after* the power calculation(s).  `i` is any integer, not just fifth-roots of integers.

Comment: In that case, i doubt you’ll find anything. Truncated expectation just isn’t a widely needed operation, beyond tuning exotic data structures and algorithms, where the bounded slowness/imprecision of FP isn’t important to the theoretical guarantees.

Comment: Btw, `i.pow(1/5).pow(2)` is 1 for all positive values of `i`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the [`num`](https://docs.rs/num/) crate to avoid precision loss:

```rust
use num::{BigUint, ToPrimitive};

BigUint::from(base)
    .pow(exp_num)
    .nth_root(exp_den)
    .to_u64() // `.try_into()` works too -- import `TryInto` instead of `ToPrimitive`
    .expect("result overflows u64")
```

([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=78b6b4c6ab4a99f5b38f0f9ed27728ff))

To achieve full accuracy, there isn't much you can do other than using big integers, so go for it if you really need the precision.  Do watch out for performance though — this calculation is quite expensive when the numerator or denominator of the exponent is large.